# .Net Maui WebView passing SVG sequence from C# to HTML page via Javascript

Tags: c#, .net, webview, maui

I am developing a .Net Maui application and I use WebView to create svg drawings on HTML page when I want to pass an SVG sequence from c# to the HTML page via EvaluateJavaScriptAsync does not work I tested and I passed a simple string works but with an svg sequence which has special characters like < and > / it doesn't work
Thanks for the help
here is the code:

```
public string SVG_Content { get; set; }

this.SVG_Content = $"<svg id='SVGPrincipal2' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='7000' height='7000'> </svg>";

   string removeSvgContentScript = $@"\
   var svgP = document.getElementById('SVGPrincipal');\
   if (svgP) {{ alert('SVG found!'); document.body.removeChild(svgP); }} else {{ alert('SVG not found!'); }}\
   var svgString = '{this.SVG_Content}';\
   var svgElement = document.createElement('svg');\
   svgElement.innerHTML = svgString;\
   document.body.appendChild(svgElement);\
  ";
  await this.webView_MainPage.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync(removeSvgContentScript);
```

Comment: SVG is XML data and you want to send the XML in an HTTP Connection (the body as HTML).  You have to make sure the Content-Type of the HTTP connection is good, and if you are using HTML that the special characters are escaped properly.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references